# JSqlParser for 'create table as ..' Query

Tags: java, sql, parsing, jsqlparser

Is there any option in JSqlParser to parse Query like

```
create table public.sales1 as (select * from public.sales)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use an older version **JSqlParser**.

The fork at https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser is able to parse this query.

I cannot recall from which version on but I think a version higher than 0.9.1 is definitly able to parse this SQL.